# Reststop Package Issue in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about the usage of Reststop package in meteor on windows platform.What i am did is :

- Download Reststop package from Reststop 2 site.
- I put Reststop package in meteor packages folder[Default Installation of meteor Packages]
- and also put  Reststop package in Meteor Project[like meteor create projectname folder]

I am try use Reststop package in windows platform.In this scenario I got one error as shown below :

```
D:\MeteorWS\demo>meteor
[[[[[ D:\MeteorWS\demo ]]]]]

=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: Package not found: reststop
    at self.api.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:132:17)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:78:11)
    at Object.self.api.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:129:9)
    at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use_handler] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\packages.js:238:11)
    at _.extend.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:483:11)
    at Object.exports.bundle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:897:12)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\run.js:698:26
    at exports.inFiber (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\fiber-helpers.js:24:12)
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I am new to Meteor.So please suggest me what to do for this issue?

Comment: how did you added package ?

Comment: Just put in package on that Folder only.Due to no availability  of mrt command on windows platform.@ajduke

Comment: Windows doesn't have the `meteor add` command yet?

Comment: If it does, you'll need to `meteor add hellogerard:reststop2` after putting RestStop in the packages folder. That should compile it into the .meteor/..../packages directory where meteor can access it at runtime. That's if it works the same as on unix systems, which I assume it does. Also, RestStop2 is deprecated, just so you know. I released a new REST API package for Meteor 0.9.0+ which is inspired and endorsed by RestStop2: https://github.com/krose72205/meteor-restivus